# Importing many columns from a CSV into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import to pgAdmin a big table with more than 100 columns. Is there any way to import the table without creating those 100 columns in a table within the pgAdmin? That would be a considerably time-consuming task.

Comment: import it from where? A File? Another Postgres Table on a Server you can access via PGAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not importing data into pgAdmin, you are importing it into Postgres, and using pgAdmin to help you in that task. Graphical tools like pgAdmin are, at heart, just convenience wrappers around the actual functionality of the database, and everything they do can be done in other ways.

In the case of a simple task like creating a table, the relevant SQL syntax is well worth learning. It will work in any database tool, even (with some minor changes) on other SQL databases (e.g. MySQL), can be saved in version control, and manipulated with an editor of your choice.

You could even go so far as to write a script in the language of your choice that generates the SQL for you based on some other data (e.g. the headings of the CSV file) - although make sure you don't run that with third-party data without checking the result or taking extreme care with code injection and other security concerns!

The Postgres manual has [an introduction to tables and creating them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-basics.html) which would be a good place to start.